# Do the uart fifos require clock domain cross and gray code?

Tags: verilog, fifo

If the UART module has a single clock input (call it `axi_aclk`), and the baudrate clock is generated from `axi_aclk` according to divisor registers (`DLL` and `DLM`).

Let's take the clocks for xmit fifo as an example below (the write port of the fifo is driven by `axi_clk`, and the read port is driven by `baudclk`:

```
        +------------>---------------------+
        |                                  |
        |                                  v
--> axi_aclk ---> [baudrate generator]     +-->[xmt fifo] <--
                         |                                  ^
                         |                                  |
                         +----------------------------------+
                                        baudclk
```

My question is, in such case, does the `xmt fifo` implementation require clock-domain-crossing logic (and gray code for read/write pointers), and why?

PS: my baud clock generating module is below (the `i_clk` into brg module is `axi_aclk`):

```
/*
 * baud-rate generate (brg) is a clock divisor which takes an input clock
 * and generate an output clock (baud16), with the following freq relationship:
 *
 *  baud16 = clk / divisor
 *
 * 
 * limitations:
 * - The minimum divisor for this module is 1. For this case, baud16 ties to i_clk.
 * - For divisor=0, the output is undefined.
 * - For odd divisors greater than 1, the duty cycle of the output will be slightly less than 50%.
 */

`default_nettype none

module uart_brg #(
    parameter DIVISOR_WIDTH = 16   // 16-bit integer, per 16550 standard
) (
    input  wire                             i_rst_n,
    input  wire                             i_clk,
    input  wire [DIVISOR_WIDTH - 1 : 0]     i_divisor,   // >0
    output reg                              o_clk        // baud16
);

reg [DIVISOR_WIDTH - 1 : 0] count = 0;
reg out;

// update count
always @(posedge i_clk, negedge i_rst_n) begin
    if (~i_rst_n)
        count <= {DIVISOR_WIDTH{1'b0}};
    else begin
        if (count == i_divisor - 1)
            count <= 0;
        else
            count <= count + 1;
    end
end

// update out
always @(posedge i_clk, negedge i_rst_n) begin
    if (~i_rst_n)
        out <= 1'b0;
    else begin
        if (count == 0 || count == i_divisor >> 1)
            out <= ~out;
    end
end

//assign o_clk = ~i_rst_n? 1'b0 : ((i_divisor == 1)? i_clk : out);
always @(*) begin
    if (~i_rst_n)                 o_clk = 1'b0;
    else if (i_divisor == 1)      o_clk = i_clk;
    else                          o_clk = out;
end

endmodule

`default_nettype wire
```

This design is targeting a Xilinx FPGA.

It uses the beh_fifo (w/o gray code) found at: [Sunburst FIFO](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002SJ_FIFO1.pdf)

If CDC is not necessary, can CDC logic and/or the FIFO be removed?

I am implementing a simplified version of Xilinx axi_uart16550.

Comment: @Mikef I am targeting Xilinx FPGA. Currently I am using the beh_fifo (w/o gray code) from <http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2002SJ_FIFO1.pdf> pp4-5. If CDC is not necessary, seems it can be further simplified to improve latency.

Comment: Basically I want to implement a simplifed version of Xilinx axi_uart16550 (as an excercise). From pg143, it seems that axi_uart16550 use a single clock (s_axi_aclk). To your another question, it seems that there is no requirement for 50% duty cycle of baud clock (so i think it can be 1 clk wide puse on the axi_aclk).

Comment: Then use one clock, the design does not require CDC of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

These two clocks may be synchronous. baudclk may be implemented by gated clock. For example, mask 3 out of 4 axi_aclk clock pulses to generate a divide-by-4 baudclk.

```
           _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
axi_aclk _| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_
           _               _               _
baudclk  _| |_____________| |_____________| |_____


axi_aclk -> clk buffer -+---------------> DFF (axi_aclk)
                        |
                        +-> clk gating -> DFF (baudclk)
```

Create a clock tree on axi_aclk, the DFFs of axi_aclk and baudclk domains will be balanced.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the question by adding my simple brg module code. If the two clocks are synchronous, then the tx/rx fifo can be much simpler, right? I am writing a simple uart module as an exercise to learn verilog. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also the latency is reduced without clock domain crossing. If your standard cell library has ICG (integrated clock gating) cells, use them for better timing control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am targeting for FPGA (a xilinx zynq evaluation board), not aware of ICG yet. Will take a look.

Comment: In Xilinx Vivado, clock gating may be converted to DFF with enable. Check Vivado Tcl command "synth_design -gated_clock_conversion auto".